# Orthonormal sequence in L$^2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, orthogonality

> Let $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an orthonormal sequence in L$^2(0,1)$. Prove that $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis iff $\forall a\in [0,1]$, $a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\int_0^a\phi_ndx|^2$.

For the first direction, this is just using Parseval's identity with $\chi_{(0,a)}$, because: $$a=\|\chi_{(0,a)}\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\int_0^1\phi_n\chi_{(0,a)}dx|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\int_0^a\phi_ndx|^2$$.

For the second direction, I tried using the fact that $\{\phi_n\}$ is orthonormal basis iff $\{\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\})^{\bot}=\{\vec 0\}$, but this didn't work. Also tried to show that Parsavel's equality must hold but also got stuck there.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What was it that did not work with your approach for the second direction?

Comment: @Thomas I wasn't able to show that if $\langle f,\phi_n\rangle=0$ for every $n$ then $f=0$

Comment: It's been a while, but I think it is true that, if  $\phi \in L^2(0,1)$ and $\int_a^b \phi (x) dx = 0$ for every $0\le a < b \le 1$, then $\phi=0$.

Comment: ... because, for almost every $x\in (0,1)$ we have $\phi(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\int_{x-\varepsilon}^{x+\varepsilon}\phi(y)\, dy$. Do you happen to know that?

Comment: Finally, if $(\phi_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is not complete, I believe you should be able to show that there is $\phi\in L^2(0,1)$ such that $||\phi||= 1 $ and $\int_a^b \phi=0$ for every $a,b$.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure I'm following you. Are you referring to what I wrote or is it another approach?

Comment: I just tried to show on my own (with, by now, somewhat rusty knowledge on the topic) that, if you have equality, then the orthonormal system is complete (by contradiction). From what you have written I'm not exactly sure what you had in mind, to be honest.

Comment: @GBA this seems like an odd condition to me, where did this problem come from?

Comment: @operatorerror My professor gave it to me as an exercise

Comment: @GBA, hey, why you deleted the Lebesgue dominated question just now? I was about to write a solution to you, please reopen it (I will delete this comment later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, it's been a while, so I suggest you try to find the error in my ways instead of just believing me.

If $B:= (\phi_n)_{n\in \mathbb{n}}$ is not complete, you will find $\phi \in L^2(0,1)$ such that $B$ together with $\phi$ is an orthonormal system.
By Bessels inequality,
$$|\int \phi fdx| + |\sum_n \int \phi_n fdx| \le ||f||^2$$ for every $f\in L^2$.
By assumption you have equality for $f=\chi_a$ for every $a\in (0,1)$, even if you omit the first term in the sum $|\int \phi \chi_a|\,dx$, so
$$\int_0^a \phi(x) \,dx = 0$$
for every $a\in (0,1)$
So $$\int_a^b \phi(x) \,dx = \int_0^b \phi(x) \,dx - \int_0^a \phi(x) \,dx = 0$$
But then,
$$\phi(x_0) = \lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2\delta}\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\phi(x) \,dx =0 $$
for almost every $x_0$, contradicting the fact that $||\phi||_{L^2} = 1$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the last result you wrote. What I did is replaced it with the following proposition: $\int_{0}^a\phi(x)dx=0$ for every $0<a<1$, so $\phi(x)=0$ almost everywhere (standard result in measure theory).

Comment: @GBA well, if you know that already, then that's also fine. But what is the problem, then? The result I used is easy to show, also - you start with continuous $\phi$ and use the mean value theorem. Then you approximate $L^1 $ functions by continuous functions. Since for bounded intervals, $L^2 \subset L^1$ you get the result in the case it is needed here.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much

Comment: @GBA the answer is proving this fact you quote from measure theory, in fact.